# Attempt by security transparent method exception

Tags: c#

I'm creating application with plugin architecture. To load external DLL files, I'm using MEF framework. All those external dlls runs in separate domains. I would like to allows the person who create module define PermissionSets that module will need to execute. However, i've got issues with loading such library becouse `container.ComposeParts(this);` throws such exception:

```
Attempt by security transparent method 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionComposablePart.Crea
 teInstance(System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo, System.Object[])' to access 
 security critical method 
'Sth.Plugins.Dummy.DummyConfigurer..ctor()' failed.

Assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Composition, Version=4.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is marked with the 
AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security 
transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in 
AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by 
default, which may be the cause of this exception.
```

Currently, I'm using such permissions:

```
var permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permissions.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution | SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlThread));
permissions.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read | FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, _codeStorage.RuntimeFolder));
```

I was thinking that when I mark class loaded in DLL as `SecuritySafeCritical` it will work but I was wrong.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I got manage to resolve this error thanks to this post and it's response:

[the-demand-was-for-permissionset-class-system-security-permissionset-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957089/the-demand-was-for-permissionset-class-system-security-permissionset-version)